# How to get IDLE to accept paste of Unicode characters?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, python-idle

Oftentimes when I'm working interactively in IDLE, I'd like to paste a Unicode string into the IDLE window. It appears to paste properly but generates an error immediately. It has no trouble displaying the same character on output.

```
>>> c = u'ĉ'
Unsupported characters in input

>>> print u'\u0109'
ĉ
```

I suspect that the input window, like most Windows programs, uses UTF-16 internally and has no trouble dealing with the full Unicode set; the problem is that IDLE insists on coercing all input to the default `mbcs` code page, and anything not in that page gets rejected.

Is there any way to configure or cajole IDLE into accepting the full Unicode character set as input?

Python 3.2 handles this much better and has no trouble with anything I throw at it.

I know that I can simply save the code to a file in UTF-8 and import it, but I want to be able to work with Unicode characters in the interactive window.

Comment: When I cut the above and paste into a 2.7 console interpreter, u'ĉ' is converted to u'c'.  I am pretty sure this is done by Windows rather than Python.  In Idle, pasting is handled by tcl/tk, as configured by tkinter. This sort of mess is part of the reason for Python 3.  Working with unicode is easiest with the most recent 3.x release, as we are constantly improving it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out a way. Since the sources to IDLE are part of the distribution you can make a couple of quick edits to enable the capability. The files will typically be found in `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib`.

The first step is to prevent IDLE from trying to encode all those nice Unicode characters into a character set that can't handle them. This is controlled by `IOBinding.py`. Edit the file, find the section after `if sys.platform == 'win32':` and comment out this line:

```
#encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
```

Now add this line after it:

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
```

I was hoping that there would be a way to override this with an environment variable or something, but `getdefaultlocale` calls directly into a Win32 function that gets the globally configured Windows mbcs encoding.

This is half the battle, now we need to get the command line interpreter to recognize that the input bytes are UTF-8 encoded. It didn't appear that there was a way to pass an encoding into the interpreter, so I came up with the mother of all hacks. Maybe someone with a little more patience can come up with a better way, but this works for now. The input is processed in `PyShell.py`, in the `runsource` function. Change the following:

```
    if isinstance(source, types.UnicodeType):
        from idlelib import IOBinding
        try:
            source = source.encode(IOBinding.encoding)
        except UnicodeError:
            self.tkconsole.resetoutput()
            self.write("Unsupported characters in input\n")
            return
```

To:

```
    from idlelib import IOBinding  # line moved
    if isinstance(source, types.UnicodeType):
        try:
            source = source.encode(IOBinding.encoding)
        except UnicodeError:
            self.tkconsole.resetoutput()
            self.write("Unsupported characters in input\n")
            return
    source = "#coding=%s\n%s" % (IOBinding.encoding, source)  # line added
```

We're taking advantage of [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to specify the encoding for each line of input provided to the interpreter.

**Update**: In Python **2.7.10** it is no longer necessary to make the change in `PyShell.py`, it already works properly if the encoding is set to `utf-8`. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to bypass the change in `IOBinding.py`.

Comment: It seems fragile. What happens if you copy-paste [ (U+1F610 NEUTRAL FACE)](http://codepoints.net/U+1F610)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I get back `'\U0001f610'`. Does it not work for you?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm using Python 2.7.1 here, I'll try it on a newer version soon. It's odd that they would be encoding to UCS-2 when Windows supports full UTF-16.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian nope, it works on 2.7.5 too. And I hope you're not going to hold me personally responsible for every bug in IDLE - obviously the hack I present here did not cause the issue.

Comment: it might depend on tk version. `_tkinter.TCL_VERSION == '8.6'` I use Python 3.4