# How to clean up troublesome characters in clipboard data so I can paste into a python script in IDLE?

Tags: string, python-2.7, clipboard, python-idle

I want to copy tables of data displayed in websites and paste as text directly into scripts as string variables using IDLE. This sometimes doesn't work because of something in the copied material that IDLE won't accept as savable. The resulting behavior is not an error message, but IDLE simply ignoring the save request. It just sits there until I close without saving.

That behavior is *fine with me at the moment* - I'd of course not want to save a python script that contains troublesome characters.

Is there some way I can get those pesky characters out of what's in my computer's clip board so I can get on with my script?

If I just needed to do this once, I could go in and look at the html of the site and possibly extract it, or in the case of [the table of satellites on this page](https://sites.google.com/a/slu.edu/swartwout/home/cubesat-database#database) maybe I can go into the google app and get it.

But for the purposes of this question, I'd like a way to "fix" the data in my clip board to I can paste as a string into a script using IDLE and run it.

I've tried "Paste and Match Style" in a `.txt` file first to clean it up, no  luck. I have Sublime Text 2 but not very familliar with it, if there is a relatively easy to use function in there, that would be OK.

Trying to paste inside triple quotes `thing = """ """` at the prompt gives the following error message: `Unsupported characters in input`:

[image]

note: *using Python and IDLE versions '2.7.11', Tk version '8.5.9' (I know, these are a year old) in OSX.*

**EDIT:** Here is a chunk of data from my clip board, as suggested in the comments. Copying from here (as shown) results in unsuccessful save attempts in IDLE, so at least some of the pesky symbols are in here. I'm pasting between a pair of triple quotes, e.g. `thing = """ """`

---

```
1   2/6/2000    PICOSAT 1&2 (TETHERED)  Aerospace Corporation   mil Opal    Opal    T   5   N   Minotaur-1
2   2/10/2000   PICOSAT 3 (JAK) Santa Clara University  uni Opal    Opal    E   2   N   Minotaur-1
3   2/10/2000   PICOSAT 6 (StenSat) Stensat Group. LLC  civ Opal    Opal    C   2   N   Minotaur-1
4   2/12/2000   PICOSAT 4 (Thelma)  Santa Clara University  uni Opal    Opal    S   2   N   Minotaur-1
5   2/12/2000   PICOSAT 5 (Louise)  Santa Clara University  uni Opal    Opal    S   2   N   Minotaur-1
6   9/6/2001    PICOSAT 7&8 (TETHERED)  Aerospace Corporation   mil Opal    Opal    T   2   D   Minotaur-1
7   12/2/2002   MEPSI   Aerospace Corporation   mil 2U  SSPL    T   2   D   Shuttle
8   6/30/2003   DTUSAT 1    Technical University of Denmark uni 1U  PPOD    E   2   N   Rokot-KM
9   6/30/2003   CUTE-1 (CO-55)  Tokyo Institute of Technology   uni 1U  PPOD    E   3   N   Rokot-KM
10  6/30/2003   QUAKESAT 1  Stanford University uni 3U  PPOD    S   5   N   Rokot-KM
11  6/30/2003   AAU CUBESAT 1   Aalborg University  uni 1U  PPOD    E   2   N   Rokot-KM
12  6/30/2003   CANX-1  UTIAS (University of Toronto)   uni 1U  PPOD    E   2   N   Rokot-KM
13  6/30/2003   CUBESAT XI-IV (CO-57)   University of Tokyo uni 1U  PPOD    E   4   S   Rokot-KM
14  10/27/2005  UWE-1   University of Würzburg  uni 1U  TPOD    E   3   N   Kosmos-3M
15  10/27/2005  CUBESAT XI-V (CO-58)    University of Tokyo uni 1U  TPOD    E   5   N   Kosmos-3M
16  10/27/2005  Ncube 2 Norweigan Universities  uni 1U  TPOD    E   2   N   Kosmos-3M
17  2/21/2006   CUTE 1.7    Tokyo Institute of Technology   uni 2U  JPOD    C   2   D   M-5 (2)
18  7/26/2006   AeroCube 1  Aerospace Corporation   mil 1U  PPOD    T   1   D   Dnepr-1
19  7/26/2006   SEEDS   Nihon University    uni 1U  PPOD    E   1   D   Dnepr-1
20  7/26/2006   SACRED  University of Arizona   uni 1U  PPOD    E   1   D   Dnepr-1
```

Comment: You could try to parse the table with Python

Comment: @cricket_007 the table is displayed on a web page in my browser, and I select it and copy to my computer's clip board. Would I be able to parse from my clipboard? I'm not a web developer, and I'm not the creator of the table.

Comment: It seems to be a Google Spreadsheet. There's an API for that

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand there are probably several "developer" ways to do this. But I am asking a different question, thanks!

Comment: Alright, well, maybe you can paste some of the troublesome strings into your question? Your question seems unclear otherwise

Comment: Looks like normal tab-demilited data to me...

Comment: @cricket_007 which makes this question interesting. Why is the Python editor IDLE failing to save scripts with this particular data, but otherwise works fine with data copied from plenty of other tables in other web sites. This is a specific, unexpected behavior and I'm trying to find out what's going on in this case.

Comment: I don't really know about IDLE. I use Pycharm or Jupyter nowadays

Comment: @cricket_007 I did specify IDLE in the title, several times in the body, and again in the tags for a reason. It's sort-of a "special" environment. Some like it, other's don't :)  I do though.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I'm simply saying that IDLE is great for simple scripts, but when actually developing, move to an IDE like Pycharm

Comment: @cricket_007 Possibly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28060419/3904031) applies.

Comment: @cricket_007 This question is about python2, where code is limited to ascii, versus python3, where code is unicode.  Unless one tries to paste astral (non-BMP) chars, it is not about IDLE versus PyCharm (and I don't know whether PyCharm handles such characters either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to scan the string and find the characters outside the normal printable range. Maybe the strange character will be easier to identify.

```
text = """ <here comes your pasted text> """

def normal(c):
  return (32 <= ord(c) <= 127) or (c in '\n\r\t')

strange = set(ord(c) for c in text if not normal(c))

print strange
```

I wonder what character codes may end up in `strange`.

Comment: I can't run any python with the thing. I've pasted an example up there, and when I copy it again, and paste even at an interactive  Python prompt, I get the error `Unsupported characters in input`. I'm wondering if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28060419/3904031) applies?

Comment: Ah!, I have another Python 2.7 installation (anaconda). Running in iTerm I can paste it at the prompt without problem. OK I will try this now.

Comment: set([195, 188]), which seem to be Ã and ¼ respectively. So I wonder if the answer to this SO question is *This is in fact probably expected behavior for the IDLE 'beginner level' IDE, perhaps as a safety precaution, but other environments may be more accepting*?

Comment: Now try to locate these characters in the text: e.g. `text.find(chr(195))`. Isn't it in a word like `Würzburg`? Neither `Ä` not `¼` should result in any trouble in a proper Unicode text.

Comment: Bingo! Problem solved. I usually don't deal with strings, this was very helpful. Thanks for the mini-tutorial!

Comment: Also need to update my IDLE and Tkinter, there may have been fixes already.